# Display text from MySQL as it is in the database

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2

I have a MySQL database with a table called `places`, this table has a column called `description`.

One sample text looks like this from the `description` column:

```
Sample text with line.
Sample detail: 12345

--------------------------
More info: test info
--------------------------
Another info
```

This format is what I need when I display the text with my Flask app. However the rendered form of the text with Jinja2 will look like this

```
Sample text with line. Sample detail: 12345 -------------------------- More info: test info -------------------------- Another info
```

I've tried to use `|safe` in the Jinja2 html page like `{{text|safe}}`, but it doesn't help.

Is it something that can be fixed? Should I handle it in my app.py with Python code, or it's a Jinja issue and it should have to done in the Jinja template?

Answer (score -1):

The line feeds/carriage return is being stripped out somewhere along the way.  You need to figure out where before you can figure out how to fix it.  The first thing I would do is identify the hex codes for the line feeds stored in the database text.  Then I'd do a simple retrieval from basic python to see if the line feeds are retained there.  That would tell you whether the issue is with Jinja or the database call itself.

Comment: They're never stripped; only, html rendering will replace them with a single space character.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was thinking of something else